# KnockoutJS calling methods with context in bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here I have an example code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: someData1">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: myFunction"></a>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: someData2">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: myFunction"></a>
</div>
```

How inside myFuncion code to know when it's called: when foreaching someData or someData2?

Answer (score 2):

You can access both the item and the click event in `myFunction`.

```
viewModel.myFunction = function (item, event) {
  // event.target = <a>
};
```

You should check out the official Knockout documentation for the [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Comment: Look, I have two tables with identical data. 1st table is populated with someData1 array collection, second table - with someData2.
But I also have some functions to manipulate that data before render.
So I want to use this functions for two data arrays. That's why I need to know from what table event came: from first which is binded to someData1 or from second - binded to someData2.
In your example you show how to get DOM element but not data which is foreaching at the moment - what I need I suppose.

Comment: Well, use `event.target`, that's why I put it in the function. `event.target.parentNode` would be one of the `<div>` elements in the example you provided. Mark each of the `<div>`s (or tables in your real case) somehow (`data-` attributes, `id` attributes, whatever) and compare the value of such attribute of `event.target.parentNode` (there will be more `.parentNode` lookups in a table; you can also use the `jQuery#parent` method).

Comment: HTML code can be fixed/changed/rewritten and this way it will broke.
Is it possible to give $parent as parameter for function I call on click?

Comment: I checked the documentation I posted and there is a very simple way to identify from which table the event originated: `data-bind="click: function (data, event) { myFunction(data, event, 1) }"`. You can then check the third argument of `myFunction` (i.e. `myFunction = function (data, event, tableId) {...}`